# How to get Workflow event type and Processstep name or Arguments in to java service in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

I created a workflow for whenever I upload or remove asset from `/content/dam/MyAsset` folder I am able to Triggering JavaServices. I create two launcher with Created Event Type and Removed Event Type.
I need to get That event Type and Process step name or arguments in to Services
inside Triggering execute function

**Here is My Code:**

```
public void execute(WorkItem arg0, WorkflowSession arg1, MetaDataMap arg2) 
                    throws WorkflowException 
{
    log.info("Workflow created ::::: ");    
}
```

Is there any way to get Launcher event type and process  arguments]to Services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get launcher event type as that information is not passed down to the workflow. What you could do is check the payload to identify if the node exists or not. The workflow called on removal will have path to the node that is removed and if you try to resolve that path it will give you exception (yeah, bad approach but thats the only possibility).

For the process step arguments passed, all that information is available in meta data. Look into `arg0.getWorkflowData().getMetaDataMap().get("MyIDkey",<Type>);` where arg0 is your `WorkItem` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler` instead? You will have all the information you need. Here is a small code snippet that waits for an event and adds the relevant data into a map that is then passed to the `JobManager` to generate a new Job that is executed by a matching `JobConsumer`:

```
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.Job;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobManager;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.consumer.JobConsumer;
// and more imports...
@Service
@Component(immediate = true, policy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, description = "Listen to page modification events.")
@Properties(value = { @Property(name = "event.topics", value = { PageEvent.EVENT_TOPIC, DamEvent.EVENT_TOPIC}, propertyPrivate = true),
                      @Property(name = JobConsumer.PROPERTY_TOPICS, value = ModificationEventHandler.JOB_TOPICS, propertyPrivate = true) })
public class ModificationEventHandler implements EventHandler, JobConsumer {
    /**
     * Modification Job Topics.
     */
    public static final String JOB_TOPICS = "de/rockware/aem/modification";

    @Reference
    private JobManager jobManager;

    @Override 
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        logger.trace("Checking event.");
        PageEvent pageEvent = PageEvent.fromEvent(event);
        DamEvent damEvent = DamEvent.fromEvent(event);
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        if (damEvent != null) {
          // DamEvent is not serializable, so we cannot add the complete event to the map.
          logger.trace("Event on {} is a dam event ({}).", damEvent.getAssetPath(), damEvent.getType().name());
          properties.put(DAM_EVENT_ASSET_PATH, damEvent.getAssetPath());
        }
        if (pageEvent != null) {
          logger.trace("Event is a page event.");
          properties.put(PAGE_EVENT, pageEvent);
        }
        logger.trace("Adding new job.");
        jobManager.addJob(JOB_TOPICS, properties);
      }

      @Override 
      public JobResult process(Job job) {
          if (job.getProperty(PAGE_EVENT) != null) {
              PageEvent pageEvent = (PageEvent) job.getProperty(PAGE_EVENT);
              if(pageEvent.isLocal()) {
                  Iterator<PageModification> modificationsIterator;
                  modificationsIterator = pageEvent.getModifications();
                  while (modificationsIterator.hasNext()) {
                      PageModification modification = modificationsIterator.next();
                      logger.info("Handling modification {} on path {}.", modification.getType(), modification.getPath());
                      if(isRelevantModification(modification.getType())) {
                          logger.info(modification.getPath());
                      }
                  }
              } else {
                  logger.trace("Page event is not local.");
              }
          } else if (job.getProperty(DAM_EVENT_ASSET_PATH) != null) {
              String assetPath = (String) job.getProperty(DAM_EVENT_ASSET_PATH);
              logger.trace(assetPath);
              backupService.trackModification(assetPath);
          } else {
              logger.trace("Invalid event type. Cannot help.");
          }
          return JobResult.OK;
      }
}
```